# Transaction would exhaust the block limits error when calling a smart contract from Polkadot JS API

Tags: smart-contract, javascript, polkadot-js

I'm trying to call a smart contract using the Polkadot JS API ([like here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.tx)). The contract function is really simple, it takes 2 strings: a key and a value as input parameters, then adds the key, value to a hashmap in the contract storage. I can call it normally in the PolkadotJs UI, but when try using the PolkadotJs Javascript API I got this error message:

```
2022-02-28 00:12:01             DRR: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits
Error: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits
    at RpcCoder._checkError (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.cjs:84:13)
    at RpcCoder.decodeResponse (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.cjs:47:10)
    at WsProvider.value (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/index.cjs:267:90)
    at W3CWebSocket.value [as onmessage] (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/index.cjs:247:153)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/home/minhnd/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:107:17)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
2022-02-28 00:12:01        RPC-CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits
```

This is my code:

```
// Required imports
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require("@polkadot/api");
const { ContractPromise } = require("@polkadot/api-contract");
const { keyring } = require("@polkadot/ui-keyring");
keyring.loadAll({ ss58Format: 42, type: "sr25519" });

const abi = require("./freshdi_metadata.json");

async function main() {
    const provider = new WsProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:9944");
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });

    const contractAddress = "5CbqJvv4VXFNsoK6nj95jD3ajopgJmrB5XP2vXHCvMekxqC6";
    const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, contractAddress);

    const alicePair = keyring.createFromUri("//Alice");

    const value = 0;
    const gasLimit = 5 * 1000000000000;

    await contract.tx
        .insertAction({ value, gasLimit }, "key_str","value_str")
        .signAndSend(alicePair, (result) => {
            if (result.status.isInBlock) {
                console.log("in a block");
            } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
                console.log("finalized");
            }
        });
}

main()
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => process.exit());
```

Comment: Can you provide the configuration of your runtime, about the parameter following:

`pub RuntimeBlockLength: BlockLength = BlockLength::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);`

Comment: @ironman_ch_parami, it's the default configuration of substrate

Comment: @ironman_ch_parami I tried with the flipper contract but the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I set the gas limit too high.
Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to contracts-UI. Then pretending to want to call the function with the parameters. Automatically the real values (max and to-be-used) are computed by the UI. You can just copy it into your code.